# (PHP) How to replace different substrings inside string using an array of values?

Tags: php, str-replace

How can I replace a set of placeholders on a string with an array of substrings?

My code:

```
$replaceWith = array('FIAT', 'car');
$message = '{%s} is the best {%s} of the world.';
$finalMessage = str_replace(array_fill(0, count($replaceWith), '{%s}'), $replaceWith, $message);

var_dump($finalMessage);
```

Outputs:

```
string 'FIAT is the best FIAT of the world.' (length=35)
```

Desired Output:

```
string 'FIAT is the best car of the world.' (length=34)
```

Thks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
<?php
$subject = '%s is the best %s of the world.';
$values = array('FIAT', 'car');
echo vsprintf($subject, $values);
?>
```